# Is there an equivalent of html datalist in Xamarin.Forms, mechanism that would allow to select predefined values but also a free-text entry?

Tags: android, html, ios, xamarin.forms, controls

We are building a Xamarin forms app.

One of the fields is supposed to be a select where you can pick one of the predefined values or enter a free text value like into the text field.

in HTML one would solve it by using `<datalist>`

```html
    <input list="browsers" name="browser" id="browser">
    
    <datalist id="browsers">
      <option value="Edge">
      <option value="Firefox">
      <option value="Chrome">
      <option value="Opera">
      <option value="Safari">
    </datalist>
```

**Is there an equivalent of HTML datalist control in Xamarin.Forms, that would allow selection of values and also a free-text entry?**

If there isn't one, how is this sort of functionality (selection of values and also a free-text) achieved in iOS and Android? as it does feel like a quite common scenario.

Comment: Anything update?

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/185337/#Comment_185337

Comment: Like [Auto Box](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/294)? Or maybe the one mentioned in the thread: [AutoSuggestBox](https://github.com/dotMorten/XamarinFormsControls/tree/main/AutoSuggestBox)

Comment: @Shaw we are using dotMorten Autobox ATM but it doesn't bind to ICommand without workarounds, and is not very usable in landscape mode. All the suggestions hide under the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

I recommend using the [Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfAutoComplete NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfAutoComplete).

> **Note**: Syncfusion can be used for Free via its [Community License](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense).

I've put together a sample app demonstrating how to use `Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfAutoComplete`: https://github.com/brminnick/AutoCompleteSample

## Walkthrough

To view the completed code from this walkthrough, visit https://github.com/brminnick/AutoCompleteSample

#### 1. Install Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfAutoComplete NuGet Package

1. In Visual Studio, add the [Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfAutoComplete NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfAutoComplete) to your iOS project, Android project and .NET Standard Project (if applicable).

#### 2. Initialize Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfAutoComplete on iOS

1. In the iOS Project, open `AppDelegate.cs`
2. In the `AppDelegate.cs` file, in `AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching` method, add `new Syncfusion.SfAutoComplete.XForms.iOS.SfAutoCompleteRenderer();`, like so:

```cs
[Register(nameof(AppDelegate))]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        new Syncfusion.SfAutoComplete.XForms.iOS.SfAutoCompleteRenderer();

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
}
```

### 3. Use Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfAutoComplete in Xamarin.Forms

Here is an example of a Xamarin.Forms app using Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfAutoComplete:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Syncfusion.SfAutoComplete.XForms;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AutoCompleteSample
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App() => MainPage = new AutoCompletePage();
    }

    class AutoCompletePage : ContentPage
    {
        public AutoCompletePage()
        {
            Content = new SfAutoComplete
            {
                HeightRequest = 40,
                AutoCompleteSource = new List<string>
                {
                    "Edge",
                    "Firefox",
                    "Chrome",
                    "Opera",
                    "Safari",
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

## Demo

This GIF was generated using this completed sample app: https://github.com/brminnick/AutoCompleteSample

[image]

Comment: Hi Brandon, thanks for the answer, sadly we are not eligible for a free license, off by one dev.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an equivalent of HTML datalist control in Xamarin.Forms, that would allow selection of values and also a free-text entry?

Xamarin.Forms don't have the same control, but you can create a custom control to have these features.

A custom control that contains Listview, Entry, and Stacklayout.

nuget `XLabs.Forms`

`Install-Package XLabs.Forms -Version 2.0.5782`

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/AutoCompleteView.cs

Then using this custom control AutoCompleteView.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <!--  this isn't working yet  -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SugestionItemTemplate">
        <ViewCell Height="60">
            <ViewCell.View>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    

                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <local:AutoCompleteView
            Placeholder="type 'firstname'"
            SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
            ShowSearchButton="False"
            SuggestionItemDataTemplate="{StaticResource SugestionItemTemplate}"
            Suggestions="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Backing class

```
public class listviewmodel:ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }
    private Command<string> _searchCommand;
    private string _selecteditem;

    public listviewmodel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Items.Add("cherry");
        Items.Add("cherry1");
        Items.Add("cherry2");
        Items.Add("cherry3");
        Items.Add("cherry4");
        Items.Add("wendy");
        Items.Add("barry");
        Items.Add("nico");
        Items.Add("leo");
    }
    public Command<string> SearchCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _searchCommand ?? (_searchCommand = new Command<string>(
                obj => { },
                obj => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.ToString())));
        }
    }


    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selecteditem;
        }
        set
        {
            _selecteditem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }
}
```

The viewmodelbase is one class that implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius You can set `TextColor="Red"` for `AutoCompleteView`

Comment: I am getting : `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Can not resolve reference: `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4`, referenced by `XLabs.Forms.Droid`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4`, or remove the reference to `XLabs.Forms.Droid`. StruebyPhotoApp.MobileApp.Android   ` I believe its out of date

Comment: FYI - The XLabs.Forms NuGet package hasn't been updated since 2015. I strongly recommend against using it.

Comment: @BrandonMinnick If you have best solution, please share it , thanks.

Comment: Yup! I provided an answer 3 days ago https://stackoverflow.com/a/66820632/5953643

Comment: @BrandonMinnick Sorry, I mistaken you for the owner of the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'Xamarin Chips' component.
for the reasons

- it supports almost all layouts
- has Input, Choice, Filter, and Action types of displays
- you can select single, multiple choices or enter the new one
- lots of UI customization options

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/chips/overview

Regards,
N Baua